# Inherit styles from button mixin inside small breakpoint

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Is there a way that I can only set $expand in the small only breakpoint and inherit the $background and $background-hover from above?

```
&__close {
    @include button($background: $success-color, $background-hover: auto);

    @include breakpoint(small only) {
        @include button($background: $success-color, $background-hover: auto, $expand: true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be a possible "middle way" to default the `button()` arguments to the some of the values in your example? Then you could rearrange the order of your arguments and only override the `$expand` value like so:

```
// @mixin button()
@mixin button( $expand: false, $background: $success-color, $background-hover: auto ) {
    // All the button stuff
}


// Your selector
&__close {
    @include button();

    @include breakpoint(small only) {
        @include button($expand: true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it would be possible, but is not the desired outcome.